# vfork leads to a memory "free()" crash, but fork doesn't, how it happened?

Tags: c++, linux, crash, fork, vfork

I was trying to see if vfork creates a child process that shared memory with father process, like below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main()
{
    int* pi = new int(5);
    int i = 5;
    pid_t id = vfork();
    if (id > 0) //father
    {
        *pi = 4;
        i = 4;
        printf("father set i=%d, *pi=%d\n", i, *pi);
        sleep(2);
        printf("father get i=%d, *pi=%d\n", i, *pi);
        delete pi;
    }
    else //child
    {
        sleep(1);
        printf("child get i=%d, *pi=%d\n", i, *pi);
        i = 3;
        *pi = 3;
        printf("child set i=%d, *pi=%d\n", i, *pi);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I expected that the value if i and *pi are shared between father and chid process, but when I executed it:
$ g++ myvshare.cpp && ./a.out

```
child get i=5, *pi=5
child set i=3, *pi=3
father set i=4, *pi=4
father get i=4, *pi=4
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid pointer: 0xb75f9000 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x67257)[0xb74ae257]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6d577)[0xb74b4577]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6dd31)[0xb74b4d31]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x18)[0xb766bd98]
./a.out[0x8048621]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x15f2d4)[0xb75a62d4]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1055312    /home/x/cpp/a.out
08049000-0804a000 r--p 00000000 08:01 1055312    /home/x/cpp/a.out
0804a000-0804b000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 1055312    /home/x/cpp/a.out
0859e000-085c3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7200000-b7221000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b7221000-b7300000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
b73d3000-b73d5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b73d5000-b73f1000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1181015    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b73f1000-b73f2000 rw-p 0001b000 08:01 1181015    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b73f2000-b7445000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1181047    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
b7445000-b7446000 r--p 00052000 08:01 1181047    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
b7446000-b7447000 rw-p 00053000 08:01 1181047    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
b7447000-b75f6000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1180977    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
b75f6000-b75f7000 ---p 001af000 08:01 1180977    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
b75f7000-b75f9000 r--p 001af000 08:01 1180977    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
b75f9000-b75fa000 rw-p 001b1000 08:01 1180977    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
b75fa000-b75fd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b75fd000-b776a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 400094     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
b776a000-b776b000 ---p 0016d000 08:01 400094     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
b776b000-b7770000 r--p 0016d000 08:01 400094     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
b7770000-b7771000 rw-p 00172000 08:01 400094     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
b7771000-b7774000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b7788000-b778b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b778b000-b778d000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0          [vvar]
b778d000-b778e000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b778e000-b77b0000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1180949    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
b77b0000-b77b1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b77b1000-b77b2000 r--p 00022000 08:01 1180949    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
b77b2000-b77b3000 rw-p 00023000 08:01 1180949    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
bf9ca000-bf9eb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Terminated (core dupm)
```

What I was confused:

> 1. I expect that vfork should differ from fork in that i and *pi are shared. But still vfork seem to have COW for i and *pi, when father sets the value, child still gets old value, and vice versa.
> 2. Why there's a core dump saying "free()" failed? I tried to change vfork to fork, no such problem. How did this happen, inside libc, or glibc?

Thanks!

Comment: This is C++, not C, new keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrong, with `vfork()`, the child doesn't share memory with the parent. The memory belongs to the parent only. `vfork()` differs from `fork()` because it doesn't copy the memory, but the behavior is undefined is you attempt to use the memory of the parent except the `pid_t` return by `vfork()`. Plus, the child must not call another function that `exit()` or `exec()` family. For example, it's undefined behavior to call `printf()` in the child. The child **need** to finish by `exit()` or `exec()`.

Finally, the parent thread is blocked until the child call `exit()` or `exec()`.

Like `fork()`, the processes created by `vfork()` inherits file descriptors, signal dispositions, and current working directory.

All information is in the [manual of vfork](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vfork.2.html).

TLDR: This is undefined behavior.